# input field is still unable to validate after validation condition has been set

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have created a select option list  with 4 options for users to select. How this select list works: Each option within the select list has additional fields, hence depending on what options user select, the additional fields will be displayed accordingly.

Hence, the 4 options in the select list are "NameA","NameB","NameC" & "Others". For options, "Name A-C", it will display the respective names as additional fields, however if the user were to choose "Others", it will prompt the user to input the name in the additional field.

All fields are mandatory

**Problem:**

1.) If I do not make any selection from the select list, it will prompt for the user to input the name. Meaning, the user will not be able to submit the form. The output that is what I wanted

2.) If user were to click "Others":

a.) deliberately miss out on the field for "Name", form wouldn't be submitted and will prompt for user to input the field. output as expected

b.) Input in the field and click submit, form will be submitted. Output as expected.

3.) The problem is that when user clicks on either "NameA", "NameB" or "NameC", the respective names will be displayed. However, when the user clicks submit, it still prompts for the user to input the name field. This is not the outcome as expected.

Outcome:

The select list is a mandatory field, user didn't select any options, form is incomplete and wouldn't submit. However, if the user were to select either "NameA", "NameB" or "NameC". form is considered complete and if user were to select "Others" and input in the name it is considered complete. However, as mentioned in point3, form upon submision always prompt for field input.

what has gone wrong? PLease help

Code:

```
<form method="POST" action="#" name="form_Agent" onsubmit="return validate()">
<div class="leftCol">
<p>
<select name ="NameDetails" id="NameDetails" onchange = "return  val(this.value);"tabindex= "7" class="required">
<option value ="" disabled = "disabled"> ..</option>
....
</select>
</p>

 <script>
 function val(x) {

    document.getElementById("extradiv").style.display = x == "Others" ? "block" : "none";   
    document.getElementById("NameA").style.display = x == "Name A" ? "block" : "none"; 
    document.getElementById("NameB").style.display = x == "Name B" ? "block" : "none"; 
    document.getElementById("NameC").style.display = x == "Name C" ? "block" : "none";
}
</script>

<div id = "extradiv" style ="display:none">
<p>
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" value="Name" title="Name" class="validateInput required" tabindex="8" />
</p>
</div>

<div id = "NameA" style ="display:none">
<p><input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" title="Name" value="NameA"  class="leftCol required validateInput" tabindex="8"/></p>
</div>

 ......(same syntax for NameB and NameC)
//Other fields in the form
<p>
<input type="text" name="gender" id="gender" value="gender" title="gender" class="defaultValue required" tabindex="9" />
</p>

</div>
</form>
```

Comment: @Teemu what do you mean?